# How to get rid of these static_casts?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-cast, pimpl-idiom

I'm trying to create a C++ class hierarchy of UI "view" classes that wrap platform-specific UI classes. My classes use the pimpl idiom to hide the implementation from the header file. The `Impl` structs contain another pointer, to classes in the platform  hierarchy.

[image]

(I used "PS" to abbreviate "platform specific".)

In the code below, I try to show a boiled down example of the base class (`View`), and one derived class (`Button`), along with the classes that they wrap.  There is a static cast in the `Button's` implementation. All of the subclasses of `View` will have a lot of these casts. Is there way define the `Impl` struct so that the compiler understands the types better here, so I don't need to use the static casts?

```cpp
// In .hh file

class View {
public:
    virtual ~View() = default;
    ...
protected:
    struct Impl;
    Impl *impl;
    View();
    View(Impl *impl);
};

class Button: public View {
public:
    Button();
    void setText(const string &text);
};

// In .cc file 

View::View() :impl(nullptr) {}
View::View(Impl *impl) :impl(impl) {}

struct View::Impl {
    PSView *psView;
};

void View::doStuff() {
    ... impl->psView ... // fine, no cast needed here 
}

Button::Button() {
    PSButton *b = new PSButton();
    impl = new Impl{b};
}

void Button::setText(const string &text) {
    PSButton *myImpl = static_cast<PSButton*>(impl->psView);
    myImpl->setTitle(text);
}
```

In my real code, it's a bit weirder, because the platform specific types are Apple's Objective-C classes. I'm putting that aside for now to try and clean up and simplify this question.

Comment: Insufficient information, and what's there is either confusing or misleading (or both).   To work out a way to remove `static_cast<NSStackView *>(impl-nsview)` it is necessary to have information about the relationship - if any - between types `NSView` and `NSStackView` - and you have provided no information about either other than that `NsView` is "platform specific, hidden from header file".   Mixing two languages doesn't help.

Comment: Actually, I said `NSStackView` is a subclass of `NSView`, but I said it in the code comment. Maybe I should move that up to the text to make it more obvious.

Comment: I've edited the question to try to improve it. Sorry about that. It was sloppy and I probably shouldn't post questions when I'm tired at the end of the day.

Comment: This sort of question comes up frequently, and there are essentially no good answers, other than using templated code (which brings its own limitations).

Comment: @Sneftel Okay. Yes, I was hoping there was a solution lurking in the dark areas of C++ that I don't yet know - the template stuff.